# Teamcity User id not matching TFS vcs user id

Tags: teamcity

When performing a check-in to TFS, the user name associated with the check-in is DOMAIN\username.  When linked to TeamCity, this is visible in TeamCity under the changes heading (Recent History).

The problem is that my users log in to TeamCity using LDAP, so their default VCS username is simply **username** and I can't see an automatic way to set the default VCS user as **DOMAIN\username**.

There are too many account to change manually to the correct VCS users so that the **My changes** functionality works.

Is there no user name style for TFS?  Is there another way around this?

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the profile page of a user(TeamCity/profile.html) and change the default user id for all TFS roots to DOMAIN/username.

IF the above steps works for one user, you can update the data in user-related  tables in the teamcity database to update it for all users

```
insert into user_property
values(<user_id>,'plugin:vcs:jetbrains.**tfs**:anyVcsRoot','DOMAIN//username')
```